# For loop is crashing in C

Tags: c, for-loop, codeblocks, scanf

**EDIT: Wow. I left out the '&' in the scanf function. Thanks for the help though.**

I'm using Code::Blocks, and I'm trying to build a simple program to prompt the user for 10 numbers and then display them. The thing is, it will print the question, but once I type a number, it crashes instead of assigning it with scanf()...code below.

```
main()
{
  int userNums[11] = {0};
  int x;
  char displayOrder = '\0';

  for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
  {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", userNums[x]); //code crashes here
  }
//code continues...
```

Comment: change to `&userNums[x]`

Comment: You will get the warning when you compile the above code. Consider warning as the error.

Comment: Instead of making assumptions, you should read the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html) of the functions you are using.

Comment: Who is upvoting this stupid question??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized, and unlikely to help anyone else searching the site later.

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

> ```
> scanf("%d", &userNums[x]); //code won't crash now
> ```

Comment: Can you explain why it was crashing?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour nobody allows, I see a yellow flash of ten other answers, before I edit, with fast up-votes :D

Answer (score 1):

Scanf read on stdin and put the result in the second argument. It must be a pointer, because the function will get a copy of the variable that you send.

Example:

```
 int i;

 scanf("Enter a number here : %d", &i);
 printf("number is %d", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remember `scanf()`'s argument must be an address (pointers). In your case `userNums[x]` needs `&` operator. Change

```
scanf("%d", userNums[x]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &userNums[x]);
```

`&` operator in front of `userNums[x]` gives the address to `scanf` to store the data input by user. In absence of `&` operator (in this case) `scanf` do not find the address where to store the input value and therefore your program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
 scanf("%d", userNums[x]); //code crashes here
```

to

```
 scanf("%d", &userNums[x]); //code crashes here
```

scanf needs a pointer to be able to change its value

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `scanf()` this way:

```
scanf("%d", &userNums[x]);
```

Explanations: You want `scanf()` to assign the value given by the user to a variable. Since, in C **parameters are passed by copies**, you need to pass the address of your variable to `scanf()` so that it can modify it. To retrieve the address of a variable, you use the `&` operator: therefor `&userNums[x]`.